# Combine two tables that have another table for relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table: Country, Country_i18 and Language.
In Country are stored all Countries in the world. In my Language table are stored my Languages: English, German...
And in my Country_i18 are stored names of Countries by Language: etc. for Finland

- EN: Finland
- DE: Finnland
- IT: Finlandia
- FR: Finlande

Table Country_i18n is related with tables Country and Language. With Country is related by CountryId and with Language with LanguageId.
Now I Want with SQL query check if for any country in my table Country see if is missing any name of country by language of **ALL** languages in my table Language.
For example: if is missing a record for country Poland in German language in my table Country_i18 I want to get something like this:

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| Country_i18ID | CountryId | LanguageID |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
|      NULL     |     1     |      1     |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

Or if record exist then:

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| Country_i18ID | CountryId | LanguageID |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
|       2       |     2     |      2     |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT tablica.ID_drzava_jezik AS 'Country_i18ID', tablica.ID_drzave AS 'CountryId', CL.Id AS 
'LanguageID'
FROM Common.Language CL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CC.Id ID_drzave, CC.Title, CCi.Id ID_drzava_jezik, CCi.Name, CCi.LanguageId
        FROM Common.Country_i18n CCi
        RIGHT JOIN Common.Country CC ON CCi.CountryId = CC.Id) tablica ON CL.Id = tablica.LanguageId
ORDER BY tablica.ID_drzave
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting your requirement correctly but I guess on your where you could just filter by country id and language id to get  the result of whether the country language name exists or not. Something like SELECT Country_i18ID,CountryId ,LanguageID WHERE CountryId=1 AND LanguageID=1; where the CountryId represents the Country you are looking for and LanguageId is the Language you are looking for.

Comment: Yes if not exist than is NULL: But I need this WHERE conditions run through all records in Country and all records in Language

Comment: Can you give an example of a result set that you expect after running your query.

Comment: You have in question example if record exist or not

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results would help -- as would a db/SQL fiddle of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT Country_i18ID,CountryId,LanguageID 
    From Country_i18 
    Right Outer Join Country on Country.CountryId = Country_i18.CountryId
    Right Outer Join Language on Language.LanguageID = Country_i18.LanguageID
    WHERE CountryId IS NOT NULL and LanguageID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It didn't work. I get the same result as with my query.